# Capitalize the first letter of each sentence in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

When first sentence finish and user press the dot function has to make other sentence first letter uppercase but when second function start to work everything mixed.

After first letter finish the second letter has limited depend on the how many char into pressed before the dot if I wrote long letter it perfectly works.

Here is the full code.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
app
  .directive('skywalker', function ($timeout) {
      return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
          var capitalize = function (sentence) {
            if (typeof (sentence) === 'undefined' || sentence === null ||
              sentence === '' || sentence.trim('') === '') { return sentence; }

            var newSentence = sentence.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + sentence.substring(1, sentence.length);

            var tempList = [];
            var sondaNoktaVar = newSentence.substring(newSentence.length-1) === '.' ? true : false;
            tempList = newSentence.split('.');
            if (tempList.length > 1) {
              var tempNewSentece = tempList[0];
              if(tempList.length === 2 && tempList[tempList.length-1] === ''){
                tempNewSentece = tempNewSentece + '.';
              }


              for (var e = 1; e < tempList.length; e++) {
                  if(tempList[e] !== ''){
                    var tempNewSenteceElma = angular.copy(tempList[e]);
                    tempNewSenteceElma = tempNewSenteceElma.trim('');
                    var elma = tempList[e].split(tempNewSenteceElma)
                    elma = elma[0];


                       
                    tempNewSenteceElma = tempNewSenteceElma.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + tempNewSenteceElma.substring(1, tempNewSentece.length);
                    
                    tempNewSentece = tempNewSentece + 
                                      (tempNewSentece.substring(6) === '.' ? '' : '.') + 
                                      elma + 
                                      tempNewSenteceElma;

                  }
              }
              newSentence = tempNewSentece + (sondaNoktaVar === true ? '.':'');


            }



            return newSentence;
          };

          element.on('keyup', function (ev) {
            if ( ev.shiftKey === true) {
             
            }
            else if (ev.which === 13 && ev.shiftKey === true) {
              
            }
            else if (ev.which === 13 ) {
              
            }
            else {
              scope.newCommentContent = capitalize(scope.newCommentContent);
            }

          });

        }
      };
    })

  .controller('capitalizeController', [
      '$scope' ,
      function($scope) {

        $scope.newCommentContent = '';

        $scope.CommentList = [];

        $scope.Clear = function(){
          $scope.newCommentContent = '';
          $scope.CommentList = [];
        };

        $scope.addNewComment = function (ev) {
          if (ev.which === 13 && ev.shiftKey === true) {
            return;
          }
          else if (ev.which === 13) {
            if (typeof ($scope.newCommentContent) === 'undefined' || $scope.newCommentContent === null ||
              $scope.newCommentContent === '' || $scope.newCommentContent.trim('') === '') { return; }
            ev.preventDefault();
            ev.stopPropagation();

            var newComment = {
              Id: ($scope.CommentList.length +1),
              content: $scope.newCommentContent,
            }

            $scope.CommentList.push(newComment);
            $scope.newCommentContent = '';
          }
          else if (ev.which === 27) {
            ev.target.blur();
            $scope.newCommentContent = '';
          }
        };

    }]);
```

```html
  
<!doctype html>
<html>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="myCtrl.js"></script>
  <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>control</title>
   <style>input.ng-invalid{border:1px sloid red;}</style>
  </head>
  
  <body ng-app="myApp">

   <br>
   <div ng-controller="capitalizeController"
   style="border:1px solid red; padding:10px">

      <br>
      Test <span style="color:blue; cursor:pointer;" ng-click="Clear()">Clear</span>
      <br>
      <div ng-repeat="comment in CommentList track by comment.Id"
      style="border: 1px solid gray;padding: 5px;width: 300px;margin: 5px;">
        {{comment.content}}
      </div>
      <br/>
      <textarea skywalker
                     ng-attr-placeholder="'Write a comment and press enter'}}"
                     spellcheck="false"
                     ng-model="newCommentContent"
                     ng-keydown="addNewComment($event)"
                     class="ca-field" style="height: 100px;width:300px"></textarea>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line

```
tempNewSenteceElma = tempNewSenteceElma.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + tempNewSenteceElma.substring(1, tempNewSentece.length);
```

You are using `tempNewSentece` in the last brackets - substring, but you should use `tempNewSenteceElma`.

Moreover, I think this part of code:

```
if(tempList.length === 2 && tempList[tempList.length-1] === ''){
    tempNewSentece = tempNewSentece + '.';
}
```

is not needed.